# How can i access to object elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am using the jQuery Gantt api, and I want to access to certain elements, but I don't know how.

```
$(function() {

        "use strict";
        //var obj = JSON.parse($(".gantt").gantt);
        $(".gantt").gantt({
            source: [{
                name: "Sprint 0",
                desc: "Analysis",
                values: [{
                    from: "/Date(1320192000000)/",
                    to: "/Date(1322401600000)/",
                    label: "Requirement Gathering", 
                    customClass: "ganttRed"
                }]
            }],
            navigate: "scroll",
            scale: "weeks",
            maxScale: "months",
            minScale: "days",
            itemsPerPage: 10,
            onItemClick: function(data) {
                alert("Item clicked - show some details");
            },
            onAddClick: function(dt, rowId) {
                alert("Empty space clicked - add an item!");
            },
            onRender: function() {
                if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function") {
                    console.log("chart rendered");
                }
            }
        });
        //alert("OK");
        //var parsedData = JSON.parse();
        //alert($(".gantt").gantt.source);
        $(".gantt").popover({
            selector: ".bar",
            title: "I'm a popover",
            content: "And I'm the content of said popover.",
            trigger: "hover"
        });

        prettyPrint();

    });
```

I found this ape with static example, but am trying to draw my own chart by changing content of element source.
so can some tell me how can i get the element source from the gantt object.

Comment: what elements do you want acces?

Comment: the element 'source'

Comment: You want to set a different source, or you want to get the current source from the gantt?

Comment: Elaborate further !!!

Comment: Try with `$(".gantt").gantt().source[0]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your example, you could simply move the source data into a variable so you can reference it later:

```
var ganttSource = [{
    name: "Sprint 0",
    desc: "Analysis",
    values: [{
        from: "/Date(1320192000000)/",
        to: "/Date(1322401600000)/",
        label: "Requirement Gathering", 
        customClass: "ganttRed"
    }]
}];

$(".gantt").gantt({
    source: ganttSource,
    ...
});

console.log(ganttSource);
```

Comment: Yup, you are right, I have to build the source element outside, then I can inject it into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expecting this?

To access `gantt` elements through object try like this.

```
var ganttObj = $(".gantt").data("gantt");
```

Or try to create `instance` for your `gantt` like this.

```
var ganttObj = $(".gantt").gantt("instance");
ganttObj.model.maxScale = "years" //To change `maxScale` property values dynamically
```

Or you can also directly access your elements like this.

For eg: To change `maxScale` value from **months** to **years**, you can use like below.

```
$(".gantt").gantt({ maxScale: "years" });
```

Please let me know if this helps you.

Comment: no doesn't work, $(".gantt").gantt() it's a constructor with data, it means that we don't have an object to parse.

Comment: Check my updated answer. You can also access your gantt elements by creating instance object.